# Объединение двух тестовых фалов по столбцам

Tags: файлы

Есть два файла: `file1.csv` и `faile2.csv`.Первый файл имеет формат (логины):

```
user4567myloginstarwars...
```

Второй имеет формат (промо-коды):

```
XXXXZZZZYYYYNNNNLOPAOOOA...
```

Каждый файл состоит из **4000000** строк.Нужно сопоставить объединить строки, чтобы на выходе получился файл, формата:

```
user4567[TAB|SPACE]XXXXZZZZmylogin[TAB|SPACE]YYYYNNNNstarwars[TAB|SPACE]LOPAOOOA...
```

Comment: а по какому критерию их объединять? есть привязка к промо-кодам? т.е. как понять что в строку  user4567 нужно вставить именно этот промо-код?

Comment: Не важно, какому пользователю какой промо-код будет привязан.

Answer (score 3):

Что может быть проще...

```
paste -d"\ n"   file1  file2 | awk '{ print $1,$4,$2,$5,$3,$6 }'
```

Comment: Большое спасибо) А можно немного рахъяснить данную конструкцию?

Comment: Утилитой paste склеиваем файлы по символу перевода строки, уберите все что после пайпа и поймете. Ну а дальше, еще проще, просто говорим в какой последовательности напечатать столбцы, с помощью awk.

Answer (score 0):

Может это?

```
join --help
```

Comment: неа. join - join lines of two files on a **common field**

Comment: так мож нумбер строки добавить первым полем? тогда всё сойдётся

Comment: можно то можно, но зачем?)